# css - user menu - two issues

Tags: css

when I hover the mouse over it, the cursor doesn't change into hand until you actually over over the text. (For example, if you pay attention to SO navigation, your cursor changes into hand as soon as you touch the gray area. I am talking about Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered navigation)

when I click on it, it borders the link-text.. like it's dotted border or something by default.  How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code for the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SO navigation, it is done in following way:

```
<li class="nav">
    <a href="...">Questions</a>
</li>

.nav a {
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

The gray area you see is actually the link itself (achieve by setting the padding). To get rid of the border, you should specify by a:link:

```
.nav a:active { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of getting the hand cursor on the entire area; either you make the link take up the entire area (perhaps by *being* the entire area), or you add the style `cursor:pointer;` to the area. (Making the link cover the whole area is usually the better option, as that also make the entire area clickable.)

To get rid of the dotted border on links when they‘re clicked:

```
a:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For (1), use the `<a>` around your whole `<div>`, not just the text, and that will make the cursor change to the hand cursor when entering the `div`.  Another way is to change the `<a>` to have a style similar to

```
a { display: block; width: 300px; height: 100px; background: orange }
```

the background is just for trying it here.  It can be removed.

For (2),  use

```
a { outline: none }
```

Comment: That is not valid code. You can't have a block element (div) inside an inline element (a).

Comment: right, it won't validate... but still is being used every where in actual practice...

Comment: Instead of using a `<div>` just use a `<span>` with `display: block;`. This will validate.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: Correct. Note that you also should make the link a block element, so that the document structure still makes sense when styled.

Comment: @Guffa: Definitely the way to go :)

Comment: @Guffa: it is valid in HTML5, so all you need to make it validate is to use the HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your CSS.

```
a:focus {outline: none;}
```

However, I believe older versions of IE will not honor this code.